# How append a row line to an existing csv file using opencsv in java efficiently?

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I generate a csv file while adding lines row by row. In other words, I append lines one by one to the end of the file. I use opencsv to read and write the csv file.

The problem is that i need to do some processing in order to have a new line. So what I am doing is reading the existing csv file (~6mb file) and addling one line and writing the file. So it is like

the file was x. I am putting one more line, the file is now x+1. This involves of course many read and write operations. How can I do it efficiently. This is not a homework, neither a log file handling. It will be done couple of times, but needs to be done as fast as possible.

Thanks.

I already thought of creating the big csv file by creating x number of smaller csv files and then merging it. It doesn't seem to be efficient. Maybe it is stupid to ask, but is there any way of adding a new line without reading and the writing the complete data since the bottleneck is that it is getting slower and slower each time a new line is appended to the file.

Comment: What happens when you create your CSVWriter with a FileWriter in append mode? It shouldn't blow away your existing data and that will allow you to do writes without reading in the whole file first.

Comment: How can I create a CSVWriter with a FileWriter in append mode? In order to create a CSVwriter, I give the file path and the data to be written or appended to it.

Comment: CSVWriter has an alternate constructor that takes a FileWriter. Make sure to create the FileWriter with the two argument constructor (file path, boolean).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just buffer your writes in a background thread (submit a bunch of lines, and whenever number > N or timeelapsed > T write to disk) Or do you always need an instantaneous consistent result?

Also, you can normally APPEND with a SEEK (cheaper than reading the whole thing). Examples are RandomAccessFile object or FileOutputStream/FileWriter with append argument. That's still somewhat expensive of course.

Finally, 6 MB isn't that big. Why not read it all in and write it lazily? Assuming this is a single JVM process, keeping it in memory is the easiest solution....

Comment: 6MB data is being represented by ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>. I am not sure if 75000 lines can be fitted into 4 GB RAM.